# Terminate scanf on EOF and ignore strings

Tags: c

I am using the following code to scan for integers input from the user until end of line occurs.

```
while (scanf(" %d", &num) != EOF) {
   printf("Do something")
}
```

This works as expected until the user inputs a string instead of an integer. The program would then endlessly keep printing `Do something`. Why is that happening?

How can I stop the loop only when End of line occurs, but ignore string inputs and only perform my logic if integer inputs have occured?

Comment: When `scanf(" %d", &num)` returns 0, read a single character.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` returns the number of input items successfully assigned. That is, in your example, `1` if a number is entered, or `0` otherwise. (Unless an input error occurs prior to the first input item, in which case it returns `EOF`.)

In case a string is entered, this fails to match `%d`, `scanf()` returns zero, the loop is entered, `"Do something"` is printed, and `scanf()` is called again.

*But the string has not been consumed by any input function.*

So the string fails to match, `"Do something"` is printed... you get the idea.

Be happy you do not access `num`, because if you haven't initialized that beforehand, accessing it would be undefined behaviour (as it *still* isn't initialized)...

Generally speaking, do not use `scanf()` on potentially malformed (user) input. By preference, read whole lines of user input with `fgets()` and then parse them in-memory with e.g. `strtol()`, `strtof()`, `strtok()` or whatever is appropriate -- this allows you to backtrack, identify exactly the point where the input failed to meet your expectations, and print meaningful error messages including the full input.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stop the loop only when End of line occurs, but ignore string inputs and only perform my logic if integer inputs have occured?

When `scanf(" %d", &num)` returns 0, read a single character and toss it.

```
int count;
while ((count = scanf("%d", &num)) != EOF) {
  if (count > 0) printf("Do something with %d\n", num);
  else getchar();
}
```